# Progress indicator in table cell while app fetches and parses data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an app that displays a table of places, that when a cell is tapped, it fetches data from a web API and parses it. However, sometimes this request takes 3-5 seconds to process. I've tried to display a spinning progress indicator in the content view of the cell, but I haven't been able to get it totally correct.

I was able to get the indicator to appear when the cell was tapped, however when I return to the table, the indicator is still visible. What's the best way to do do this?

Comment: How did you add the spinner? When you return, it's still visible, what do you mean, returns from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach this issue:

- when the cell is clicked, store the `indexPath` (or some other reference) so you know which cell was clicked
- add the spinner
- make an async call to get the data from your data source
- when the async call returns, update the appropriate data in your array (or wherever you store the data for the table)
- call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to reload just the cells that changed, and remove your spinner.